# Unit test Angular form and subFormGroup

Tags: angular, forms, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Getting an error when trying to build the form in the test spec. The form build function also build a sub form array. Looking for the best way to test this

**component.ts**

```
buildForm() {
    return this.peopleForm = this.fb.group({
      people: this.fb.array([this.buildSubFormGroup()]),
      effective_date: [this.firstOfNextMonth(), Validators.required]
    });
  }

buildSubFormGroup(type: string = 'primary') {
    return this.fb.group({
      type: [type],
      first_name: ['', Validators.required],
      last_name: ['', Validators.required],
      dob: ['', Validators.required],
      gender: ['', Validators.required],
      uses_tobacco: ['', Validators.required],
      affordable_care: ['', Validators.required],
      is_pregnant: [''],
    });
  }
```

**component.spec.ts**

```
it('should be able to build the peopleForm', () => {
    component.buildForm();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.peopleForm.controls['type'].value).not.toBeNull();
  });
```

**Error:**
Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control element with name: 'effective_date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `detectChanges()` the component is initialized. Check the following:

1. Are you running a `beforeEach` function before the `it()` function?
2. Why are you returning the assignment? When is the buildForm function called in your component? Better to cause the call than re-running it.
3. What is your HTML. Try to bind on `[FormControl]` instead of `formControlName`

The idea in unit testing is to cause actions that call the respective functions.

Example:
`ngOnInit` when the detectChanges() is called.
`onClickSomething` when you click the item that calls it, not by calling the compoment.onClickSomething function.

You are testing the component on the whole.

For more information, please add the html and the entire component code.